# Is it possible to jump into slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Is it possible to get a link to a specific slide? As soon as I select the link in my example the slider does not work anymore. Only the list item without function is displayed. When you select the link the slider should scroll to the corresponding slide. Is there a possibility for this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#one">SLIDE 1</a>
<br>
<a href="#two">SLIDE 2</a>
<br>
<a href="#three">SLIDE 3</a>
<br>
<a href="#four">SLIDE 4</a>
<br>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">
    <p>&gt;</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">
    <p>&lt;</p>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="one">SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;" id="two">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li id="three">SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;" id="four">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to more work here - so this is what I did:

**I.** First I created a *slideRight* function that has a `callback`:

```
function slideRight(callback) {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
      callback();
    });
}
```

**II.** Modified the links with an *attribute* `data-peek` that links to the corresponding slide like this:

```
<a href="#" class="peek" data-peek="one">SLIDE 1</a>
```

**III.** Now the following script will do the magic:

```
$('a.peek').click(function() {
    slide($('#slider ul'), $(this).attr('data-peek'));
  });

  function slide(el, peek) {
    if (el.find('li:nth-child(2)').attr('id') !== peek) {
      slideRight(function() {
        slide(el, peek);
      });
    }
  }
```

See demo below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };


  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function slideRight(callback) {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
      callback();
    });
  }

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

  $('a.peek').click(function() {
    slide($('#slider ul'), $(this).attr('data-peek'));
  });

  function slide(el, peek) {
    if (el.find('li:nth-child(2)').attr('id') !== peek) {
      slideRight(function() {
        slide(el, peek);
      });
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="peek" data-peek="one">SLIDE 1</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="peek" data-peek="two">SLIDE 2</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="peek" data-peek="three">SLIDE 3</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="peek" data-peek="four">SLIDE 4</a>
<br>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">
    <p>&gt;</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">
    <p>&lt;</p>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="one">SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;" id="two">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li id="three">SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;" id="four">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

And here is a solution without using a custom attribute - using `id` instead:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };


  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function slideRight(callback) {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
      callback();
    });
  }

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

  $('a.peek').click(function() {
    slide($('#slider ul'), $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]);
  });

  function slide(el, peek) {
    if (el.find('li:nth-child(2)').attr('id') !== peek) {
      slideRight(function() {
        slide(el, peek);
      });
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}
a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="peek" id="link_one">SLIDE 1</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="peek" id="link_two">SLIDE 2</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="peek" id="link_three">SLIDE 3</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="peek" id="link_four">SLIDE 4</a>
<br>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">
    <p>&gt;</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">
    <p>&lt;</p>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="one">SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;" id="two">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li id="three">SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;" id="four">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great example. Is this also possible without data-peek?

Comment: if you can use numbers 1,2,3 etc instead of `one`,`two`,`three` etc. I guess it is possible

Comment: Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: well, I was talking about changing the markup such that if I click the `2`nd link for instance the card with `id` 2 can be peeked... the current implementation though is as good as that... :)

Comment: hm ok, i will try that. Thank you! :)

Comment: @alice pls accept answer if this answer fully met your requirements :)

Comment: I need a solution without data-peek, therefore not quite fulfilled. Your solution is really good, thanks again :)! I can only work with IDs and links, where I need the slider :(. (Wordpress Menu)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128932/discussion-between-alice-and-kukkuz).

Comment: @alice Hi alice, check it out now... I replace data-peek with IDs... check it out and let me know, thanks!